# Why does the temperature of the early Universe decrease as it expands?

Tags: thermodynamics, cosmology, temperature, space-expansion, big-bang

According to the Big Bang theory, the universe cooled down as it expanded. I would like to know why does the temperature decrease? And by "why" I mean **how**. What causes the temperature to decrease, what's is the physical process?

For simplicity, let's consider the early Universe after protons and neutrons formed but before the molecules appeared, so we have something resembling a monatomic gas. Temperature of such gas is defined in terms of the average kinetic energy $\epsilon_{avg}$ of the particles: $$T = \frac{2}{3}\frac{\epsilon_{avg}}{K_{boltzmann}}$$

If the temperature $T$ decreases, then the $\epsilon_{avg}$ must decrease. By what causes $\epsilon_{avg}$ to decrease? A popular explanation for an ideal gas in a cylinder is that the particles do work on the retracting piston and lose energy. But can we apply this explanation to the expanding Universe? I don't think so.  If the particles lose energy, where does this energy go? The particles do not collide with the edge of the universe (the imaginary "piston"), since there is nothing for them to collide with. There is no edge, since the whole space is expanding.

Comment: http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/db275/Cosmology/Chapter3.pdf

Comment: Maybe the cooling is due to something similar to the Joule-Thomson Effect, where an expansion of e *real* gas into vacuum produces a cooling due to a conversion of kinetic energy of the molecules to potential energy.

Comment: In the epoch you're describing, the universe was radiation-dominated, not matter-dominated. In a radiation-dominated universe, there is a pretty appealing semi-hand-wavy explanation for cooling, which is simply that cosmological expansion stretches the wavelengths of photons. *If the particles lose energy, where does this energy go?* General relativity doesn't have any conserved, scalar measure of energy, except in special cases like asymptotically flat spacetimes. This is why, for example, a photon in the present-day universe can lose energy due to cosmological expansion.

Comment: I’ve wondered this too except arrived at a different conclusion.  The universe can only be cooling upon expansion if it began as hot and dense.  It is not clear why it should start out as ‘hot’.  Wouldn’t adiabatic cooling suggest that the earliest of universe began as cold and dense (as cold as it could possibly be)?  In which case this problem would go away.  The universe would warm up as it expanded rather than cool, background radiation being a measure of its warmth.  I’m not claiming I know.  I don’t.  But the supposition that the universe started as hot needs warrant.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've already identified the concept to think about, it's not that the particles are losing energy, it's that the expanding universe is decreasing the pressure of this theoretical gas, and Temperature is pressure dependant, being more or less a measure of energy density.

Comment: This cannot be the answer! If you expand an ideal  gas into a larger vacuum vessel, the pressure decreases without a change in temperature. Only of you adiabatically expand the volume by moving the walls of the gas vessel, you will get a temperature decrease because of the work done by the gas on the walls.

Comment: I believe this answer is discussing this in more detail than I managed. https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/57080/93704